# extract fasta files starting with same name in each of the directory into a single output file

Tags: bash, filenames

I have multiple directories with multiple fasta files in those directories. I am trying to concatenate all files starting with a specific name in each of the directory into a single file.
hpa_C.seq
PANS_1_2__hpaC.fasta    PANS_4_2__hpaC.fasta    PNA_02_12__hpaC.fasta  PNA_07_7__hpaC.fasta   PNA_18_9S__hpaC.fasta   PNA_98_12__hpaC.fasta  PNA_99_3__hpaC.fasta
leu_D.seq
PANS_1_2__leuD.fasta    PANS_4_2__leuD.fasta    PNA_02_12__leuD.fasta  PNA_07_7__leuD.fasta   PNA_18_9S__leuD.fasta   PNA_98_12__leuD.fasta  PNA_99_6__leuD.fasta
nta_A.seq
PANS_1_2__ntaA.fasta    PANS_4_2__ntaA.fasta    PNA_02_12__ntaA.fasta  PNA_07_7__ntaA.fasta   PNA_18_9S__ntaA.fasta   PNA_98_12__ntaA.fasta  PNA_99_6__ntaA.fasta

I tried the following script to concatenate all the fasta files starting with names PANS_1_2 into a output file

```bsh
for sample in *.seq;do 
  echo -en $sample
  cat *.seq/PANS_1_2*.fasta
done > xyz
```

The script however is returning sequences multiple times in the output file.

Comment: Could you please format the example with the {} (code) tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cat *.seq/PANS_1_2*.fasta > xyz` already concatenates all `fasta` files. The `for` loop multiplies that by the number of `seq` files.